# Is it possible for someone to not remember something, but to remember that one used to remember it?

Tags: memory

Is it possible for someone to forgot an incident or memory, yet still remember that one used to remember it? If so, can someone give me an example?

Comment: I had to pass a year of Calculus in college in order to enter the profession I'm in, and I passed with good grades, so I must have understood it and remembered it for the exams. Yet I cannot recall anything about calculus today except for the general appearance of the equations. Does that count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the kind of situation you're looking for, but doesn't the classic 'walking into a room and forgetting why' qualify? You remember that you had a task you set out for, you started that task by walking into the room, but now you can't remember what the task was. It might not quite be right because you're in the middle of the task, so "remembering" might not be the right word for those specific instances, but I've had similar occurences more than once where I suddenly remember there was *something* I was supposed to do, but it can take quite some time to remember what it was if the memory comes back at all.

It reminded me of this scene https://youtu.be/9HXeRx828gM as well, so I don't think it's only me that's had that experience :D

*I can't help but chuckle at the fact I just linked a 2 and a half men clip in an answer about psychology*

Comment: This has a name: [Doorway effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorway_effect).